# Cross-validated methods as a default

Tags: cross-validation, scikit-learn, lasso, elastic-net, lars

Scikit-learn ( http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.linear_model ) provide classes for Lasso, ElaticNet and Lars etc both with and without cross-validation.

What are the advantages of performing these tests without cross-validation and why not always use the crossvalidated modules?